# Bash script - Nested If Statement for If File Doesn't Exist

Tags: bash, if-statement, nested

I'm trying to compile a script that will read user input, and check if the file after the y/n statement. Then it will make files executable. I think the problem with my script is conditional ordering but check it out yourself:

```
target=/home/user/bin/

cd $target
read -p "This will make the command executable. Are you sure? (y/n)" CONT
if [ "$CONT" == "y" ];
then
  chmod +x $1
  echo "File $1 is now executable."
else 
  if [ "$(ls -A /home/user/bin/)" ];
  then
    echo "File not found."
  else 
    echo "Terminating..."
  fi 
fi
```

As I said, I need the script to scan for the file after the y/n statement is printed. The script works fine how it is but still gives the "file is now executable" even if the argument file doesn't exist (but just gives the standard system "cannot find file" message after the echo'd text).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script is mostly correct, you just need to check if the file exists first. Also, it's not the best practice to use `cd` in shell scripts and not needed here.

So re-writing it

```
#!/bin/bash
target="/home/user/bin/$1"

if [[ ! -f $target ]]; then 
    echo "File not found."
else 
    read -p "This will make the command executable. Are you sure? (y/n) " CONT
    if [[ $CONT == "y" ]]; then
        chmod +x "$target"
        echo "File $1 is now executable."
    else
        echo "Terminating..."
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Downvoted. If you're using ``#!/bin/bash`` shebang, then use ``[ ]`` instead of ``[[ ]]``. Otherwise you have to quote parameters, for example ``if [[ ! -f $target ]];`` OR ``if [ ! -f "$target" ];``. chmod line is wrong as well, it must be ``chmod +x "$target"``. Don't forget about the ``if [[ $CONT = 'y' ]];``.

Comment: whoops, just noticed a typo. It should be "use ``[[ ]]`` instead of ``[ ]``". I'm voting up now because you have fixed your code ;) If somebody did not get the point, then please visit [this link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.24foo_.3D_.22bar.22_.5D)

Answer (score 1):

To get an understanding:

- Your script will take one argument (a name of a file).
- You ask if you want to make that file executable.
- If the answer is 'yes', you make the file executable.
- Otherwise, you don't.

You want to verify that the file exists too?

I'm trying to understand your logic. What does this:

```
if [ "$(ls -A /home/user/bin/)" ];
```

suppose to do. The `[ ... ]` syntax is a test. And, it has to be one of the valid tests you see [here](http://man.cx/test). For example, There's a test:

- -e  file: True if file exists.

That mean, I can see if your file is under `/home/user/bin`:

```
target="/home/user/bin"
if [ -e "$target/$file" ]  # The "-e" test for existence
then
    echo "Hey! $file exists in the $target directory. I can make it executable."
else
    echo "Sorry, $file is not in the $target directory. Can't touch it."
fi
```

Your `$(ls -A /home/user/bin/)` will produce a file listing. It's not a valid test like `-e` unless it just so happens that the first file in your listing is something like `-e` or `-d`.

Try to clarify what you want to do. I think this is something more along the lines you want:

```
#! /bin/bash

target="/home/user/bin"
if [ -z "$1" ] # Did the user give you a parameter
then
    echo "No file name given"
    exit 2
fi

# File given, see if it exists in $target directory
if [ ! -e "$target/$1" ]
then
    echo "File '$target/$1' does not exist."
    exit 2
fi

# File was given and exists in the $target directory

read -p"Do you want $target/$1 to be executable? (y/n)" continue
if [ "y" = "$continue" ]
then
    chmod +x "$target/$1"
fi
```

Note how I'm using the testing, and if the testing *fails*, I simply exit the program. This way, I don't have to keep embedding `if/then` statements in `if/then` statements.

Comment: Downvoted as well. Read my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532980/bash-script-nested-if-statement-for-if-file-doesnt-exist#comment30704265_20533317) to see why your quoting is wrong.

Comment: I usually use `[[ ... ]]`, but `[[` is not an alias to `test` while `[` is. (They're both builtin to BASH). For beginners, having the `test` manpage to refer to is very handy. I'll update my answers to make sure I have everything quoted.

Comment: No, ``[[ ]]`` is recommended for beginners. First of all, if they forget to quote a variable in ``[[ ]]`` then nothing wrong will happen, in fact, it's the right way to do it. Another reason is that people usually come with a knowledge of another programming language, where conditionals work in a different way than a ``test`` command. So they will expect ``[ ]`` to be some special syntax, but it isn't. When searching for help you should do ``help [``. If you want to get the list of all possible flags, then use ``man bash`` and search for ``CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS``.